# Editar o Agregar PieChart.Series

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
PieChart1.Series.Clear();
        List<PieSeries> collection = new List<PieSeries>()
        {
            new PieSeries
            {
                Title="Tigo",
                Values = new ChartValues<int>{10}
            }
        };
        try
        {
            PieSeries series = new PieSeries();
            series.DataContext = collection;
            PieChart1.Series.Add(series);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```

Como puedo hacer para agregar o editar series en un piechart, tengo un elemento

> wpf:PieChart

y quisiera que vaya de acuerdo a la base de datos. Ya tengo los valores listos solo para pasarlos pero no se como puedo hacer para editar los valores existente o agregar nuevos valores.

Comment: Ese es un elemento estandar de wpf? si no lo es, deberias proporcionar un enlace diciendo de donde lo sacaste.. si lo es, la documentacion no esta? no ayudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si esto les sirve a alguien pues yo no encontré información acerca de esto. Resulta que tras buscar e intentar varias cosas (que al final no tenían mucho sentido) trate de obtener el index de PieChart.Series y para mi sorpresa funciono.
Así que, si alguien tiene esa duda así se edita el valor de una serie:

```
PieChart1.Series[0].Values = new ChartValues<int> { Convert.ToInt32(Data[4]) };
```

Donde 0 pertenece al índice de tu serie, y lo que va entre {} es el valor que le asignaras a la misma.
Además, el valor que se representa en el grafico y su porcentaje lo obtienes así:

```
public Func<ChartPoint, string> PointLabelTigo { get; set; }
PointLabelTigo = chartPoint => string.Format("{0}({1:P})", Convert.ToInt32(Data[4]), chartPoint.Participation);
```

Que no se si será ir a la redundancia ubicando su valor 2 veces, pero es la única forma que conozco de colocar un porcentaje a la par de acorde al valor en mi base de datos. Y así puedes editar tu grafico con otros valores.